# making a word processer but i am having trouble keeping the words spliting up over serval lines

Tags: python

i want to keep all words together and not have half on one line and half on the other. any help is great :)

```
linewidth = int(input("input the length of a line"))
string = input("input your string")
count1 = 0
count2 = 1
def output():
    global count1
    global count2
    outputstring = string[(count1*linewidth):(count2*linewidth)]
    print(outputstring)
    count1+=1
    count2+=1
for i in range(int(((len(string)/linewidth)+1))):
    output()
```

linewidth is for how many characters on one line
string is for the characters

example:
for linewidth put in "7"
for string put in "you walk my dog"
OUTPUT:
"you wal
ked my
dog  "
but i want all it like:
"you
walked
my dog"

Comment: How does `"i walk my dog"` turn into `"you walked my dog"`?

Comment: Use the `textwrap` module. `wrapped = textwrap.wrap(string, linewidth, break_long_words=False)` `print('\n'.join(i for i in wrapped)`

Answer (score 1):

```
linewidth = int(input("input the length of a line"))
string = input("input your string")

current_line_width = 0
for word in string.split():
    if current_line_width + len(word) + 1 <= linewidth:
        print(word, end=" ")
        current_line_width += len(word) + 1
    else:
        current_line_width = len(word) + 1
        print("\n" + word, end=" ")
```